# Basic pySQLite example?

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

Gang,  I am beginning to play around with pySQLite and I'm trying to find an example that illustrates how to query the db for existing records before inserting a new record if it doesn't already exist in the db. I feel I am overlooking a very basic function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `UNIQUE` keyword when creating the table, and use `INSERT OR INGORE` to insert only if the record is "new" (unique):

```
connection=sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (bar INTEGER UNIQUE, baz INTEGER)')
```

Here we insert the row once:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES (?, ?)',(1,2))
```

Trying to insert the row again fails:

```
try:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES (?, ?)',(1,2))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError as err:
    print(err)
    # sqlite3.IntegrityError: column bar is not unique
```

`INSERT OR IGNORE` inserts the record only if it `UNIQUE` constraint is passed:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES (?, ?)',(1,3))

cursor.execute('SELECT * from foo')
data=cursor.fetchall()
print(data)
# [(1, 2)]
```

To create a `UNIQUE` index on multiple fields, use something like

```
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE foo (bar INTEGER, baz INTEGER, bing INTEGER, UNIQUE (bar, baz))''')
```

Here are links to info on

1. [INSERT OR IGNORE](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)
2. [UNIQUE constraints](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)